# nginx reverse proxy ignoring server_name

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx reverse proxy which accepts SSL requests and then passes them to an SSH tunnel to another server. It is ignoring server_name and I do not know why.

It loads this config first...

```
server {
        listen 94.156.189.160:80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Then it does the reverse proxy for one site...

```
server {
        listen 94.156.189.160:465 ssl;
        server_name humanstore.io;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/humanstore.io/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/humanstore.io/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";

        location / {
                 proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 proxy_set_header Connection "";
                 proxy_buffering off;
                 client_max_body_size 0;
                 proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                 proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

server {
        server_name humanstore.io www.humanstore.io;
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://humanstore.io$request_uri;
}
```

And then another...

```
server {
        listen 94.156.189.160:443 ssl;
        server_name infantile.xyz;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/infantile.xyz/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/infantile.xyz/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";

        location / {
                 proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 proxy_set_header Connection "";
                 proxy_buffering off;
                 client_max_body_size 0;
                 proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                 proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

server {
        server_name www.infantile.xyz infantile.xyz;
        listen 94.156.189.160:80;
        return 301 https://infantile.xyz$request_uri;
}
```

It also has other configs much like the two above, but for them they are ignoring server_name and trying to use infantile.xyz's SSL certificate giving NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. For some reason infantile.xyz is taking over the others. A diff reveals no big differences in configuration.

Comment: You only have one server using port 443. So all https requests will be handled by that one irrespective of server name. Should `humanstore.io` be listening on port 443 too? Also, unless you really need to, don't specify the IP address in the `listen` directive.

Comment: Set different port in each site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is too many `listen` directives for one server block.

One should change `listen 94.156.189.160:80` to `listen 80` and `listen 94.156.189.160:443` to `listen 443` on each server config file.